# How do I set up JavaScript in Sublime 3?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, sublimetext3

I am new to JavaScript and wanted to set up my work environment. My problems might be basic or I look totally in the wrong direction so please advise me.

I am used to work with Sublime 3 and wanted to use it for writing JS code as well.

I spend half of a day on reserach for various autocomplete/support plugins for JavaScript but none of them seems to be working properly. Topics on subject are either outdated or misleading.

For example, none of them recognizes basic objects like:
`document.`  or `window.onload` etc. (there is no autocompletion although it would be highlighted properly).

I tried:

- [JavaScript Enchancements](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaScript%20Enhancements) and [Completions](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaScript%20Completions) - they don't work. I have read that there are some issues with running those two on Windows
- [Babel](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Babel) - doesn't have autcomplete

So in the end my question is: How do I set up Sublime and JavaScript or how can I get basic autocompletion in for JavaScript in Sublime 3?

Comment: Is it any better if you use VS code? I have done React Native projects using VS Code, and the auto completion seemed to work relatively well (apart from some occassional issues with not being able to detect the functional components properly).

Comment: Eventually  if none solution for sublime i would. I don't think it is a good idead to have another IDE/text edtitor just for JS.

Comment: Yeah definitely. It doesn't make sense to use another IDE just for JS. However, VS code's language support is huge. I use it for php, JS, python, reading config files, csvs and more... Best of all, it's a free IDE.

If sublime doesn't work for you ultimately, give VS Code a try. I think you'll like it.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions

- You can use JSHint
- You can use Ternjs
- You can use Emmet
- You can use SublimeCodeIntel
- You can use Zen Coding
- Generate .sublime-completion file manually
- Adding Snippets [Custom](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-guide-to-preserving-your-wrists-with-sublime-text-snippets-7541662a53f2/)/[PackageControl](https://packagecontrol.io/search/js%20snippets)/[GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=sublime%20javascript%20snippet&p=1&ref=searchbar&type=Repositories&l=)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried LSP? It works for both ST3 and ST4.
https://github.com/sublimelsp/LSP-typescript